# Importing user-uploaded CSV into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to write a script that will save the contents of a user-uploaded CSV file into a MySQL database. I am not interested in saving the file permanently on the server -- the whole point is to just allow the user to create multiple entries in the MySQL database via a bulk upload.

Here's what I have so far.

HTML upload form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="BulkUploadStudents.php" method="POST">
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

PHP script that saves the contents of a CSV file into a MySQL database

```
<?php

$username="";
$password="";
$database="";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$file_handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/file.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

$query = "INSERT INTO students VALUES ('','$line_of_text[0]','$line_of_text[1]','$line_of_text[2]')";
mysql_query($query);

}

fclose($file_handle);

echo "<p><b>Records succesfully imported</b></p>";

?>
```

I basically just need some advice on how to connect the two. I am thinking it would be as easy as naming that PHP script BulkUploadStudents.php, creating a variable for the uploaded file name, and then replacing the "example.com/file.csv" with the variable. Not sure about the specifics, though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've asked numerous questions on this site, yet you've never got an answer you were happy with. Why do you keep coming back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the temporary file insted of the url:

```
$file_handle = fopen($_FILES["uploadedfile"]['tmp_name'], "r");
```

Comment: good, but not required as: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant localhost - assumed 'localhost'

Comment: $file_handle = fopen($_FILES["$_FILES["uploadedfile"]"]['tmp_name'], "r") produces the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: You've added quotes before the $

Comment: And you can make your code more concise by using `while($line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024))`

Comment: Oops, that was my bad...bad copy/paste. Now just have $file_handle = fopen($_FILES["uploadedfile"]['tmp_name'], "r"); but it's now producing a HUGE number of errors all across the board.

Comment: It sounds like your csv is incorrect then. You could try fgets and do some error-checking. Let's see your csv.

Comment: The CSV file at this point is super small...basically three rows, each row has three elements separated by commas. When I upload the CSV to the server and hardcode the URL path, it works.